# how to deploy web application directly from git master branch

Tags: github, dart, polymer, gitlab, google-compute-engine

For educational purpose, I am writing a server instance in GCE(google compute engine) to serve a few web apps mostly (to be) written in Dart and Polymer.

My workflow is, when my students log-in the server above, they will automatically fork those web apps into their own registries in their own server instances for further development.

My issues are,

1. How to serve web applications(they are git registries as well) in GCE like Github Pages?
2. Is it possible to manipulate Github Pages to serve web apps mostly using Dart and Polymer packages?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please add a few more details about what you try to accomplish?
What has this to do with Dart? I guess you need a web platform that supports fetching updates from a Git repository. You could create a Dart package on the server and add the Git repo as a dependency. `pub upgrade` should fetch the latest files.

Comment: What about invoking `git clone` from your server? (just asking to better understand your use case). Does the Git repo contain the source or the build output (deployable)?

Comment: yes..after 'git clone', how my fellow students can see those cloned web apps directly in browsers(not source code in registry)?

Comment: Is it possible? log-in their own servers => clone my web apps into their Git repository with the live web application

Comment: They just have to do a git clone from your repo and then run pub build / pub serve in CLI.

Comment: Hi, @Robert. which language do you recommend for the CLI process? Could you describe more concrete process for the task? I guess writing a Dart command line app for it.

Answer (score 1):

I found out answers to my questions.

```
1. How to serve web applications(they are git registries as well) in GCE like Github Pages?
```

Use CI(continuous integration).

```
2. Is it possible to manipulate Github Pages to serve web apps mostly using Dart and Polymer packages?
```

No.

---

My question is summarized to the sentence that 'Is it possible to assign IP addresses on index.html files in git repositories?'. If possible, there is no need of CI processes at all as 'A repository itself is A web server or directory running the code'.

CI is more or less documented in Github Pages and Gitlab CI etc. Though details are different, they commonly use hooks(or webhooks) to notify something from repo to another server(s), which are application servers.

In my opinion, GIT is NOT designed and has NOT evolved for web applications, but for 'REAL' applications needing compile/build processes. So, there is no mechanism to run a repo as a web server. So, the only solution is to hack the source code of Gitlab etc. to make a better Github Pages(it supports only static pages, and NOT JS and other libraries etc.).

- Disclouse: based on the advice of Günter Zöchbauer

Comment: Hi Do, can you give me some hints as to how to install Dart on GCE and deploy a simple server? I can already do this on my laptop using the Dart Editor but I have no idea how to do it on the server. Thanks!